# The maclaurin series $ f(x) =\frac {x^3} {2+ x^2}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I know we have exams today and I am doing practise since our lecture; said we need to review our Maclaurin series and I found this question and I wanted to know how one would approach it.

Find the maclaurin series of $$ f(x) =\frac {x^3} {2+ x^2}$$ also state the interval anad radius of the convergence.

Comment: $$=x^3/2\left(1+x^2/2\right)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i would approach it, and for sure try and see if you will get my answer. According to your question.[image]

[image]

Comment: In the second and third lines, I think it should be $(-1)^n$, rather than $(-n)^n$

Comment: Thanks for the correction. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write it as $$\frac{x^3}{2 + x^2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{x^3}{\left(1 + \frac{x^2}{2}\right)}$$

and use $$\frac{1}{1  +x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

write $$\frac{x^3}{2 + x^2} = \frac{x^3/2}{1+x^2/2}$$ now this is the sum of a geometric series with the first term $x^3/2$ and the ration $-x^2/2,$  therefore it is $$\frac12x^3 - \frac14x^5 + \frac18 x^9 + \cdots $$